# Issue exporting animation with blend keys to FBX

Tags: export, .fbx

I'm working on a project where I have a character that has its eyelids controlled by blend keys. I'm trying to export the animation to FBX in order to then export it for various targets in our pipeline. I've been using an app from the mac app store called "FBX review" (from autodesk I believe) to test the exported file. I've had success exporting regular bone controlled animations but have never been able to get the eyelid animation.

I've been looking for an answer for a few days now and here are some things I have tried:

I've unchecked 'apply modifiers' in the geometry options of the export settings because it has a warning about preventing shape key export

I've tried exporting the file with the other version of FBX exporter that comes with blender

I've tried exporting with the 'baked animation' option on and off

Is exporting a blend key animation to FBX just not supported in blender? Really hoping I'm just doing something wrong here and someone has an answer.

Comment: It would be helpful if you make a smallest not-working version of that problem as a .blend file and include it in your question. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exporting option to support your blendshapes (infalible) is to export a .dae
On the panel options check "EXPORT SHAPE KEYS".
Voilá.

My sincere gratitude if you vote me as the answer.

ps: Yes, I also use Autodesk's FBx review. Normally (2016 FBX format) will BRING in all keyshapes in the model (works in Unity as well).

But a blast from the past with .DAE and go long!

BFCT_Schiller

Comment: unfortunately, I haven't had any luck getting the shape keys out even with that option selected =( I ended up solving my issue but in a completely different way. I'm exporting to FBX and then to GLTF and then to collada. Weird process but it works lol

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on that process @MattSich? I'm currently facing a similar problem with my animation

Comment: @Tyler Turns out the tools I used to preview the animations didn't support blend shapes but once I made the conversion to GLTF, the preview program I have for that format displayed the blend shape animations. The conversion to collada from there is much more involved and is part of my company IP now but it's basically a custom xCode app that does the conversion.

Comment: Thanks very much @MattSich! That's enough information for me to figure out my own solution! Great work finding this work around!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get shape key animations to export with Blender's default fbx exporter.

In the .fbx export settings uncheck "NLA strips" and "All Actions" under bake animation.

Comment: This indeed worked for me and I searched for 2 days for a solution. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a character I assume you have an armature built, shapekey animation needs to be driven by a bone using drivers.

Create a non-deformable bone as part of your rig and use it to drive the value of the shapekey, this should export with the FBX just fine.

[image: shapekey driver]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by removing/applying the *Edge Split* modifier that I had on my mesh.

It seems that it cancel all Shape Key on FBX export, I assume it's due to the vertex number change in the operation.

Potentially any modifier that have an impact on the vertex count could be a problem for Shape Key export.